# Can't Change Toolbar Color From Different Class

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I am trying to change toolbar color from different class, but always failed. I don't know, what's wrong?

I've tried to do this using `LayoutInflater` but still failed. Can you help me to solve this issue?

***LoadColor.java***

```
public class LoadColor {

    private Context context;
private HomeActivity hA;
    final String KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX = "SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX";

    public LoadColor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void LoadPreferences(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, null,false);

        LayoutInflater tiup = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View homeAct = tiup.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null,false);

        Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) homeAct.findViewById(R.id.toolbarHome);
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) contentView.findViewById(R.id.radioSex);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt(KEY_SAVED_RADIO_BUTTON_INDEX, 0);
        RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
        savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);

        RadioGroup genderGroup = (RadioGroup) contentView.findViewById(R.id.radioSex);
        RadioButton male = (RadioButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.theme1);
        RadioButton female = (RadioButton) contentView.findViewById(R.id.theme2);

        if (genderGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
            hA = new HomeActivity();
                hA.setToolbarColor(tb, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
        else {
            if (male.isChecked()) {     // one of the radio buttons is checked
                hA = new HomeActivity();
                hA.setToolbarColor(tb, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    ((Activity) context).getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#014a53"));
                }
            }
            else if (female.isChecked()) {
                hA = new HomeActivity();
                hA.setToolbarColor(tb, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    ((Activity) context).getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#db503d"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***activity_home.xml***

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarHome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

***HomeActivity.java***

```
private LoadColor Lc;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        //toolbar logo and desc
        Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarHome);
        setSupportActionBar(topToolBar); //munculkan menu ke toolbar
        topToolBar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ikon);
        topToolBar.setLogoDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.logo_desc));
        Lc = new LoadColor(this);

        Lc.LoadPreferences();

    } //OnCreate

public static void setToolbarColor(Toolbar toolbar, @ColorInt int color) {
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
```

You can see the `setStatusBarColor` code in `LoadColor.java` it's work, but in the toolbar `setBackgroundColor` it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are writing a lot of code just for changing the color of a toolbar, don't you think so?

Comment: In your LoadColor class, you can write a simple static function which accepts a view and a color as an argument and changes the view (toolbar's) color accordingly. That way you don't inflate any layout which can improve your apps performance

Comment: I did this because I want set toolbar color from settings automatically. When the button in setting page is checked, it will change the toolbar color. The problem is not what you said.

Comment: Can you write me more clear code?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your onCreate or wherever you want to change the toolbar color you may call this static utility function and pass it the reference of the toolbar for which you want to change the background. This of course happens after you have identified which color you want to use for the background.

```
//Tools.java
public static void setToolbarColor(Toolbar toolbar, @ColorInt int color) {
    toolbar.setBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

For example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    //toolbar logo and desc
    Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbarHome);
    setSupportActionBar(topToolBar); //munculkan menu ke toolbar
    topToolBar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ikon);
    topToolBar.setLogoDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.logo_desc));

    //determine which color you want to use for the toolbar's background here
    //you may use a local method to do that and return the resource value
    //it can be an int resource or it can simply be a stored resource. 

    Tools.setToolbarColor(toolbar,getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));

    //you can also parse the color from a string
    setToolbarColor(topToolBar, Color.parse("RED"));

} //OnCreate
```

Comment: Don't inflate the settings view like that. Are you not showing it with a PreferenceScreen?

Comment: Yes, understand. But the code should be executed inside `male.isChecked()` and `female.isChecked()`. What I have to do?

Comment: It should be displayed depends on `SharedPreference`